# Query to get all simple products which are not part of a complex product

Tags: product, collection

Exactly as the title suggests, how can i find all simple products in the system that are not part of complex products such as configurable?

I dont mind if this is done directly in the db or through some collection load but i need only the list of product ids that fit this criteria.

Comment: Do you want a list of the simple products not currently assigned to a configuration product, or a list of simple products with all POSSIBLE simple products that *could* be part of a configurable product (i.e. have the right attribute values)

Comment: Anything not currently assigned would be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    entity_id
FROM
    catalog_product_entity
WHERE
    type_id = 'simple'
AND(
    entity_id NOT IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT
            (product_id)
        FROM
            `catalog_product_super_link` /* assocciated product ids of configurebles */
        UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT
                (linked_product_id)
            FROM
                `catalog_product_link` /* assocciated product ids of grouped */
    )
)
```